# Drawing Polygon on Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, dictionary, polygon

I'am trying to draw a polygon with about 260 coordinates on my Map. But I cant figure out why the polygon is not drawn ? There are no null references in the PolygonOptions nor are their wrong data.

```
 protected void drawOverlayPolygon(JSONArray coordinates) {
    PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    if (coordinates != null) {
        int j = 0;
        while(!coordinates.isNull(j))
            j++;
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>(j);
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            try {
                JSONArray latlng = coordinates.getJSONArray(i);
                // latlng = coordinates.getJSONArray(i);
                if (latlng != null) {
                    LatLng point = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(latlng
                            .getString(0)), Float.parseFloat(latlng
                            .getString(1)));

                //  rectOptions.add(point);
                    points.add(point);
                    Log.i("LatLng Polygon",
                            Float.parseFloat(latlng.getString(0)) + " / "
                                    + Float.parseFloat(latlng.getString(1)));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // }

        }

        rectOptions.addAll(points);
        rectOptions.strokeColor(Color.RED);
        rectOptions.fillColor(Color.BLUE);

        Polygon polygon = mapFragment.getMap().addPolygon(rectOptions);
        polygon.setVisible(true);


        Polygon polygon2 = mapFragment.getMap().addPolygon(
                new PolygonOptions()
                        .add(new LatLng(0, 0), new LatLng(0, 5),
                                new LatLng(3, 5)).strokeColor(Color.RED)
                        .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
    }
}
```

For testing I added a simple Polygon (polygon2) and it gets drawn. I am parsing the coordinates from a JSON File. I logged the corrds and they seem to be alright. One thing I noticed is that die JSONArray coordinates contains null references.

Can anybody give me a clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx Steffi I tried to add that but did not work. Everyone who runs in this problem check if the order of your Lat Lng Coordinates is correct. Otherwise your polygone is drawn somewhere in the nowhere :)

Comment: yep :) only had to replace the index `LatLng point = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(latlng.getString(1)), Float.parseFloat(latlng.getString(0)));` depends how your coordinates are formated in your JSON File

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
rectOptions.visible(true);
```

before adding the Polygon to the map.